# Configure Auto Generated Table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am having troubles trying to figure out how to rename and configure an autogenerated table, from entity framework.

Here is my code:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {
     public virtual List<ApplicationUser> AddingFriends { get; set; }
     public virtual List<ApplicationUser> AddedFriends { get; set; }
 }
```

The result expressed by those entities once migrate to the database is as the following:
[image: GeneratedTables]

So I basically just want to rename this table and its column names.
Besides that I also want to create a second table for blocked people which would have the same lists of entities. So basically when I add two other lists of application users it binds those property to this actual table shown below.
Is there a way to control generated tables and configure them correctly?

Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the Fluent API Documentation i found that i could configure that with by adding those lines of code to OnModelCreating method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(c => c.AddedFriends)
            .WithMany(c => c.AddingFriends)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("Friends");
                m.MapLeftKey("AddedUser");
                m.MapRightKey("AddingUser");
            });
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(c => c.BloquedUsers)
            .WithMany(c => c.BloquingUsers)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("Bloqueds");
                m.MapLeftKey("BloquingUser");
                m.MapRightKey("BloquedUser");
            });
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are using code first approach and this keeps track of the model and database table corresponding to that model.So, You **cannot** change the model.Options are to enable migration or to disable model checking.
 
check this link for migration
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: The migration is already enabled and i can change the model. The problem is not about if i can change the model or not. The problem is how to configure my model with fluent API or with other ways so that i can access the autogenerated table from the code shown above, and perform a renaming on both the table that is generated automatically by entity framework according to it's conventions and the columns name associated to that table.